# How to parse embeded keywords without white-space in scala

Tags: parsing, scala

I'm trying to split input by some keywords without delimiter like white-space.

```
object MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def expr = (text | keyword).+
  def text = ".+".r ^^ ("'"+_+"'")
  def keyword = "ID".r ^^ ("["+_+"]")
}

val p = MyParser
p.parse(p.expr, "fooIDbar") match {
  case p.Success(r, _) => r foreach print
  case x => println(x.toString)
}
```

This outputs as below.

```
>> 'hogeIDfuga'
```

But I really want to do is like this.

```
>> 'hoge'[ID]'fuga'
```

It seems `text` engulfs all the characters. I tried to express [`text` does't contain `keyword`], but I could't. How to express it in regex or scala parser? or any other solutions?

I have seen some posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770569/how-to-combine-regexp-and-keywords-in-scala-parser-combinators) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528333/parser-combinator-how-to-terminate-repetition-on-keyword), but they don't work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

First, `keyword` is a constant word so you don't need a regex, a plain string is enough.
Second, a `text` is some string that doesn't contain a `keyword`, not any string. Try this:

```
import util.parsing.combinator._

object MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def expr = (text | keyword).+
  def text = """((?!ID).)+""".r ^^ ("'"+_+"'")
  def keyword = "ID" ^^ ("["+_+"]")
}

val p = MyParser
p.parse(p.expr, "fooIDbar") match {
  case p.Success(r, _) => r foreach print
  case x => println(x.toString)
}
```

As for the trick of writing a regex that `not matching` something, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/448141).